# Python, how to rename file with chinese characters

Tags: python, file, chinese-locale, chinese-simplified, chinese-traditional

Can't rename file with chinese characters

I tried this

```
os.rename(file, file.replace(os.path.basename(file),"") + f"{str(filename)}.{filemenu.get()}")
```

and this

```
shutil.move(file, file.replace(os.path.basename(file),"") + f"{str(filename)}.{filemenu.get()}")
```

but it gives me error when i try to rename file with chinese characters

1 code gives `OSError: [WinError 123] Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома: 'C:/Users/danil/OneDrive/Документы/kwork/zvukogram/outputtest\\prj_23897614_d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e_1694617003.mp3' -> 'C:/Users/danil/OneDrive/Документы/kwork/zvukogram/outputtest\\今天 天气 很冷吗?.mp3'` error, 2 code gives `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:/Users/danil/OneDrive/Документы/kwork/zvukogram/outputtest\\今天 天气 很冷吗?.mp3'`

Comment: _but it gives me error_ Are we supposed to guess what the error is?

Comment: Show us the **full** error traceback message please.

Comment: ok here is full errors

Comment: This is almost certainly nothing to do with Python and everything to do with Windows; and *may be* specific to your Russian localization of Windows.

Comment: how do i solve it?

Comment: Filenames can't include `?` characters

Comment: ohhhhh me stupid

Comment: Try to rename the file to the chosen text ***by hand***, and only after it works that way can python have any chance.

Answer (score 0):

Beep..bop...boop...

Renaming files with Chinese characters can sometimes be tricky due to encoding issues.
Try specifying encode when renaming file.
Use UTF-8 to do so.

```py
new_name_encoded = new_name.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: So you have a bytes object that can't be used with rename.... helps how?